# How to download google drive files in .NET MVC without manually sign in to google account?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api

I can currently download the files from google drive, but I have to sign in my google account in browser before proceed the work. How can I avoid this. 
If you need extra information I can provide Thanks.

Comment: I followed almost similar thing, the problem is when I first run the project, it redirects me to sign in my google account first

Comment: Would this be helpful since you have no code showing? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth

Comment: You need to authenticate your calls to Drive API somehow. That means your client needs a valid access token for the API to be accessed. You can avoid authenticating multiple times using a stored refresh token that you can get by using valid credentials and giving consent to your app. With it you can then make authorized calls to the API without having to give consent each time. Did you try this?

Comment: I somehow managed it, and its working, but when I deploy the code in server then its not working @Aerials

Comment: Please add code to your question. Read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before you do. Thank you.

Comment: I've got my answer. Actually you need to have a service account. then there will be no human intervention. Thanks for you response @Aerials

Comment: @TareqMahmudHridoy please post an answer to the question so that it does not stay unanswered. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Google Drive API v3**

If you are only accessing a google drive account that you control. Then you should consider using a service account. Suppose you want to download/upload/rename some of your own google drive account data then you don’t need to manually authenticate to google drive login portal so you don’t need to redirect to your web app as well i.e. there will be no need for user interaction and a consent screen to popup. If you are going to be accessing data that belongs to another user then you should be using Oauth2.

So first you need to make a new user in service account. Think of a service account as a dummy user. You can pre authorize a service account granting it access to your data. So I can take the service account’s email address and share with it a directory on my Google Drive account then it will have access to upload to that directory on my google drive account.
You should consider using a service account if you are going to be accessing private data that you the developer own,

**Steps to get the credential:**

**Step1:**
First Make a project in https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager

**Step2:**
go to the library under APIs and services search Google Drive API and enable it.

**Step3:**
After creating a new project, go to the credentials under APIs and services and click on create credentials

**Step4:**
Select Service Account and fill a name in service account name and press done

**Step5:**
Select Service Account option under IAM and Admin and go to the Add key tab and create a new key there. Select key type as JSON

**Step6:**
Then click on credentials under APIs and services and Download the json file from service accounts scope

**Step7:** You have to share the new dummy service account in your google drive, and give him editor permission [the folder or files you want to work with ].

 
**Create credential using the secret:**

```
 UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(@"F:\client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
            
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None).Result;
            }
```

**Create google drive API service:**

```
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Generate a life time refresh token using Google playground.
2. By using OAuth flow you can generate access token from the generated refresh token.
3. Once you have a access token, you can connect google drive service/api using that access token.

I have used the similar approach for uploading YouTube videos from code into my account.

Note : You have to generate access token again once it gets expired.